# Query between two tables but to show also if there is no data in one of the tables

Tags: php, mysql

I want to query one table then join second table but if there is no data in second table to show only what is in first table.

So there is table `orders` and table `payments` what I'm trying is something like this

```
SELECT orders. * , payments. * 
FROM orders
INNER JOIN payments ON orders.user_id = payments.userID
WHERE orders.user_id =3
AND payments.processed =  ''
OR payments.processed >=  '0'
```

This query return some strange results.. Currently there are 3 records in table `orders` and 2 records in table `payments` for `user_id = 3`. It should return me 3 records at all because they are 3 in `orders`. But it is returning me each record from `orders` twice.. i.e. 6 results.

What I'm missing here?

Comment: make bracket between and and or like AND (payments.processed =  ''
         OR payments.processed >=  '0')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens due to lack of parenthesis on the `AND` and `OR`'s, `AND` has precedence over `OR`:

```
SELECT orders. * , payments. * 
FROM orders
INNER JOIN payments ON orders.user_id = payments.userID
WHERE orders.user_id =3
    AND (payments.processed =  ''
         OR payments.processed >=  '0')
```

Your query as it is being evaluated like this:

```
WHERE (orders.user_id =3 AND payments.processed =  '')
    OR(payments.processed >=  '0')
```

Another thing that can multiply the results is that each order has more then one payments .

Comment: Again each record is 2 times.. they must be 3 because I have 3 records in `orders` + 2 in `payments` I must see total of 3 records.

Comment: Payment is only one for each order.

Comment: For each order, is it one for each user? You are joining by `user_id` not `order_id` @Stan

Comment: May be there should also have `and orders.order_id = payments.orderID`?

Comment: But each user can have 134 orders for example. I want to show to him all his orders and join payment table to show him which is paid and which is not

Comment: Yes you should join by order_id ! , try only `order_id` , not both. If that doesn't work, try both.

Comment: But how? I've made it like this `...INNER JOIN payments ON orders.order_id = payments.orderID  WHERE orders.user_id =3...` and the results is empty

Comment: Ok with `ON orders.order_id = payments.orderID` i've got result but only which is paid.. I don't get orders from `order` table which are not paid.. i want to show also them

Comment: Then change the join to a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN` and change it to `ON (orders.order_id = payments.orderID AND (payments.processed =  ''
         OR payments.processed >=  '0')) WHERE orders.user_id =3` @Stan

Answer (score 0):

Well depending on your Query sou talbes must look a bit like that:

```
Orders:
ID | user_ID | ...
---+---------+----
01 |       3 | ...
02 |       3 | ...
03 |       3 | ...

Payments:
ID | userID  | processed | ...
---+---------+-----------+----
01 |       3 |           | ...
02 |       3 |     1     | ...
```

Now my question is why are you joining on the user ID ?
Of cours you database runs for each Order the join and looks how many Payments are found with the same userID. So that means for each three Orders with user_id=3 it finds two Payments with userID=3. That is 2*3=6 so six rows are selected just as you said.

If you want to select all orders with a associated payment there must be a relation between payments and orders. And in your case its a relation with one ordeer can have 0-1 payment that means your datatable should look a bit like that:

```
Orders:
ID | user_ID | ...
---+---------+----
01 |       3 | ...
02 |       3 | ...
03 |       3 | ...

Payments:
ID | userID  | OrderID | processed | ...
---+---------+---------+-----------+----
01 |       3 |    01   |           | ...
02 |       3 |    02   |     1     | ...

FOREIGN KEY Payments.OrderID -> Orders.ID
```

In this case cou can join Payments.OrderID as s foreign key on Orders.ID.

**IMPORTENT:**
If you want to get all Order Rows, you have to use a LEFT JOIN and no INNER JOIN!

```
SELECT orders. * , payments. * 
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.OrderID = orders.ID
WHERE orders.user_id = 3
...
```

Maby you should show us you database structure so we could take a look at your actual refrences between you tables.

Comment: There is no foreign keys between them. But I successfully query them by joining now and I show paid orders. But I want to show unpaid also so all I want is to show order even if there is no record in `payments`